# Coded UI Test Builder Inspector

Tags: vb.net, wpf-controls, coded-ui-tests

So I want to implement coded Ui Tests, since we still test manually at our company.
Somehow just nothing works, more specifically:
So there is a wpf UserControl with 4 Textboxes. But in the Test Builder it only shows 2 of the 4 Textboxes. Also the inspector doesnt shown any properties which were defined by me.

1. How do I make all the ui elements visible (or at least the ones that have their x:Name defined in xaml)?
2. How do I make custom properties visible (for example: Public Property myProp as String)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try to inspect 'UiItemCustom' and check of it has 4 children.

```
var _UiItemCustom = new WpfCustom(UiMainWindowWindow); //the father of this element is your Main Window element

_UiItemCustom.SearchProperties.Add(WpfCustom.PropertyNames.ControlType, "Custom");
_UiItemCustom.SearchProperties.Add(WpfCustom.PropertyNames.Name, "**THE CUSTOM NAME HERE**");

if(UiItemCustom.GetChildren().Count == 4){
   //if the custom has 4 children the it has 4 textboxes (Maybe)
}

//if you want to hold the 4 textboxes in your hand then do the following.
var _textBox1 = new WpfEdit(_UiItemCustom.GetChildren()[0]); //TextBox1
var _textBox1 = new WpfEdit(_UiItemCustom.GetChildren()[1]); //TextBox2
var _textBox1 = new WpfEdit(_UiItemCustom.GetChildren()[2]); //TextBox3
var _textBox1 = new WpfEdit(_UiItemCustom.GetChildren()[3]); //TextBox4
```

if you want to fill one of the textboxes with values, then do the following:

```
_textBox1.Text = "Hello World;
```

Answer (score 0):

The example is C# but you could easily convert it to vb.net: http://converter.telerik.com/

1. You can loop through your ui elements in a recursive way to get all the children:

   ```
   /// <summary>
   /// Returns a complete tree of controls and child controls in a recursive way.
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="parentControl"></param>
   /// <returns></returns>
   public ParentControl GetChildControls(UITestControl parentControl)
   {
       ParentControl parent = new ParentControl();

       if (parentControl != null)
       {
           List<ParentControl> children = new List<ParentControl>();

           foreach (UITestControl childControl in parentControl.GetChildren())
           {
               children.Add(GetChildControls(childControl));
           }

           parent.Children = new KeyValuePair<UITestControl, List<ParentControl>>(parentControl, children);
       }

       return parent;
   }
   ```

The parent class:

```
    public class ParentControl
    {
        internal KeyValuePair<UITestControl, List<ParentControl>> Children { get; set; }
        internal string Value
        {
            get
            {
                return Children.Key.Name;
            }
        }
    }
```

2. see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh552522.aspx